# Unable to load USB library, no module named PIL K40 whisperer laser install

Tags: python, usb-installation

I got a K40 laser cutter from eBay and am trying to install K40 whisperer on Ubuntu Focal Fossa, spent about 8 hours yesterday wrestling with it now I surrender. I have seen a post from a few years back saying it doesn't work on Ubuntu but have seen others saying they have it working.

I have downloaded the software from [Scorch Works](https://scorchworks.com) and been following the read me file in the zip explaining installation on Linux.

> Setting up K40whisperer on Linux (by Dr. med. Jan Schiefer):
>
> ## Requirements
>
> Prerequirements:
>
> - python
> - unzip
> - udev
> - inkscape

xxxx `--version` gives:

```
Python 2.7.18rc1
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.
Inkscape 0.92.5
udev command not found
```

But I have udev installed it so I assume this command just don't work with udev

> ### Instructions
>
> 1. Create a group for the users who are allowed to use the laser cutter: `sudo groupadd lasercutter`
> 2. Add your yourself to this group, replace [YOUR USERNAME] with your unix username: `sudo usermod -a -G lasercutter [YOUR USERNAME]`
> 3. Eventually add other users who will use the laser cutter to the group
> 4. Plug in your laser cutter to your computer
> 5. Create a udev control file four your laser cutter as root (i will use gedit in this example): `sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/97-ctc-lasercutter.rules`
>
>    Put the following text into the file and replace [VENDOR ID] and [PRODUCT ID] with the information you obtained from lsusb:
>    `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5512", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", MODE="0664", GROUP="lasercutter"`

`lsusb` gave me the same values for vendor id and product id

> Now save the file.
>
> 6. Reboot your computer!
> 7. Download and the K40whisperer source code, for example "K40_Whisperer-0.07_src.zip"
> 8. Unzip the source code, for example: `unzip K40_Whisperer-0.07_src.zip -d /home/[YOUR USERNAME]/`
> 9. Go to the K40 whisperer source directory, for example: `cd /home/[YOUR USERNAME]/K40_Whisperer-0.07_src/`
> 10. Install the requires python packages using the following commands:
>
>     ```
>     pip install lxml
>     pip install pyusb
>     pip install pillow
>     pip install pyclipper
>     ```

I had issues with this and had to use `pip3 install xxxx` to get it to work but have since used `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip3 1` which seems to have cleared that issue.

> 11. Run K40whisperer: `python ./k40_whisperer.py`

when I run that command I get this:

```
:~/Downloads/K40_Whisperer-0.52_src$ python ./k40_whisperer.py
Unable to load USB library (Sending data to Laser will not work.)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./k40_whisperer.py", line 28, in <module>
    from svg_reader import SVG_READER
  File "/home/dot/Downloads/K40_Whisperer-0.52_src/svg_reader.py", line 35, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

I have seen posts saying the PIL error is related to out of date pip which is what lead me to updating pip which didn't seem to work, and `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip3 1`

I'm still very new to Linux so I'm just doing what I'm told really rather than having any understanding of what/why I'm doing it.

Comment: It seems 0.49, 0.50 and 0.51 was strictly dependent of Python 2 (as per read me file) and I'm not sure if 0.52 works with 0.52. Which version did you download? It's a very baad idea to make `pip` an alternative to `pip3` since pip is specifically for Python 2 and pip3 is for Python 3. You've actually downloaded pip3 packages using pip which obviously can't be used by Python 2. Did you try running the script with Python 3?

Comment: I just installed it, and using python3 it ran 100% as is.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies installations got failed. Maybe you didn't notice it.
You need to install Pillow again, in order to do that you need first

python-dev

Make sure you are using the right version,

sudo apt-get install python2-dev